# Stop all docker containers in a specific stack (keeping the config folders intact)

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I just want to make sure I do not destroy my configs when stopping the stack.

I launch a stack with `docker-compose -f docker-compose-t2.yml up -d`.

How do I stop all the containers within this specific stack, making sure that I keep everything that was in their config folders ?

Comment: Do you want to retain the config files inside the docker container after stopping it?

Comment: The config files are kept on a volume linked into from the container.

Comment: Not sure if that's clear : in my case the config file are kept on my nas and I point to them by mounting a volume in the docker.

Comment: Then destroying the containers wouldn't delete the files.

Comment: You can stop all the containers using `docker-compose -f docker-compose-t2.yml down`. This wouldn't delete your config files.

Comment: When you "remove" a container, you only lose data that was inside the container and wasn't mounted on some other file system. Other than that, everything will remain intact.

Comment: OK great thank you ! You can put that up as an answer if you want. Might help other newbies...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case it's useful to another newbie and as per [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61778992/stop-all-docker-containers-in-a-specific-stack-keeping-the-config-folders-intac?noredirect=1#comment109278496_61778992) :

`docker-compose -f docker-compose-t2.yml down`